# R:wireframe and a huge number of plots by conditioning on factors

Tags: r, lattice

I want to make wireframe plots from the package lattice with the formula
argument

```
      formula= Y~ X1+X2|X3*X4*X5*X6*X7
```

for X1,X2 being continuous covariates and X3-X5 factors. Each factor has more than 3-10 levels.
Are there any possiblities that R doesn't make the plots tiny and that one can break them in peaces?

i.e. from this whole plot to

[image]

to smth like

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

or even

[image]

[image]

etc
etc

Comment: You could subset the data appropriately and plot in steps.

Comment: Thanks- I haven't seen that. But how can I *subset*?  I tried to do this with wireframe(Y~X1+X2|X3*X4*X5,mydata, subset=mydata[ ,4])                                                                                               (mydata is my dataframe) . Also I noticed that *lattice* automatically divides the whole panel in 2x2 grids, although it I would like 2x3 or 3x3 grids.

Comment: With mydata[,4] I mean conditioning on a single factor, like *HEALTH* with levels *Good*, *Bad*

Comment: see the `layout` parameter under `?xyplot`, which should apply to `wireframe` as well I think?  ` ‘layout’ is a numeric vector of length 2 or 3 giving the number of columns, rows, **and pages** (optional) in a multipanel display.`

Comment: Thank you both for your answers!

Comment: With `subset=` you need to tell lattice which data (rows) to use.  So maybe something like `subset=Health=="Good"` for one plot and then `subset=Health=="Bad"` for another

Comment: And then if you make several plots, you may find the  `split` and `position` arguments to `print` useful to arrange on one page.  See, for example, the answer at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29261189/produce-single-plot-and-conditioning-plot-in-trellis-graphics